# Clean up dates in different date formats (such as 3/14/2019, 03-14-2019, and 2015/3/19) by replacing them with dates in a single, standard format

Tags: python, regex

Task is:
Clean up dates in different date formats (such as 3/14/2019, 03-14-2019, and 2015/3/19) by replacing them with dates in a single, standard format.

Cannot figure out how to finish it

```
import re

text = "3/14/2019, 03-14-2019, and 2015/3/19"

datePtn = re.compile(r"""(
(\d{1,4}) #group 1
(-|/|\.) #separator group 2
(\d{1,2}) #group 3
(-|/|\.) #separator group 4
(\d{1,4}) #group 5
)""",re.VERBOSE)

matches = []
findallResult = datePtn.findall(text)
for group in findallResult:
    if len(group[1]) > 2:
        dateNew = '/'.join([group[3],group[5],group[1]])
        matches.append(dateNew)
    else:
        dateNew = '/'.join([group[1],group[3],group[5]])
        matches.append(dateNew)

newDates = []
month = ''
day = ''
for date in matches:
    for group in datePtn.findall(date): #group is tuple
        if group[1][0] == "0":
            month = group[1][1]
        else:
            month = group[1]
        if group[3][0] == '0':
            day = group[3][1]
        else:
            day = group[3]
        newDate = '/'.join([month,day,group[5]])
        newDates.append(newDate)
print("new dates")
print(newDates)

oldDates = []
for i in findallResult:
    oldDates.append(i[0])
print("old dates")
print(oldDates)
```

I could get two list with old and new dates. How to make a string, where only dates are replaced?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`dateutil` fits this use case nicely.

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse
text = "3/14/2019, 03-14-2019, and 2015/3/19"

pattern = r'(\d+-\d+-\d+|\d+\/\d+\/\d+)'
for match in re.findall(pattern, text):
    dt = parse(match)
    print(dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
```

output:

```
2019/03/14
2019/03/14
2015/03/19
```

Just replace your desired pattern in the `strftime` call.

Answer (score 0):

I could get the result I want, but have to list all date formats in the text separately.

```
import pyperclip,re

content = str(pyperclip.paste())
dateRegex1 =re.compile(r'''
    (\d{1,2})               
    (/|-)                       
    (\d{1,2})                           
    (/|-)                         
    (\d{4})                             
    ''', re.VERBOSE)
content = dateRegex1.sub(r'\1-\3-\5',content)
dateRegex2 =re.compile(r'''
    (\d{4})               
    (/|-)                       
    (\d{1,2})                           
    (/|-)                         
    (\d{1,2})                             
    ''', re.VERBOSE)
content = dateRegex2.sub(r'\3-\5-\1',content)
print(content)
```